# Check validity of generated parameters for SIDH

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, elliptic-curve-generation

In section 4.1 of the paper *[Towards quantum-resistant Cryptosystems From Supersingular Elliptic Curve Isogenies](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/506.pdf)* by Feo, Jao and Plût it is described how you generate valid parameters for the SIDH scheme. After finding a suitable supersingular elliptic curve, you pick two points $P_A$ and $Q_A$ in $E[l_A^{e_a}]$ of order $l_A^{e_A}$ for Alice. As they form a basis for $E[l_A^{e_a}]$ they need to be independent of each other. For that, you should compute the Weil pairing and check if the order is $l_A^{e_A}$.

So I started using Jao's example sage snippet which can be found on [github.com/sidh-crypto/sidh-sage-reference](https://github.com/sidh-crypto/sidh-sage-reference/blob/master/SIDH-RI_128.sage). The parameters are the following:

```
lA = 2
lB = 3
eA = 63
eB = 41
f = 11
p = lA ^ eA * lB ^ eB * f - 1

F.<z> = GF(prime^2, modulus=x^2+1)
E = EllipticCurve([F(1), F(0)])

PAx = F(2374093068336250774107936421407893885897*z + 2524646701852396349308425328218203569693)
PAy = F(1944869260414574206229153243510104781725*z + 1309099413211767078055232768460483417201)
PA = E(PAx,PAy)
QA = E(F(-PAx),F(z*PAy))
```

It's a supersingular curve with the requested cardinality and the points $P_A$ and $Q_A$ seem to have the right order $l_A^{e_A}$:

```
sage: E.is_supersingular()
True
sage: factor(PA.order())
2^63
sage: factor(QA.order())
2^63
```

But when I calculate the Weil pairing for $P_A$ and $Q_A$, I end up with a order of $p=l_A^{e_A} \cdot l_B^{e_B} \cdot f - 1$ and not $l_A^{e_A}$:

```
sage: pairing = PA.weil_pairing(QA, lA^eA)
sage: pairing
1324361388592786441589732914656853536873*z + 3172046595776778884104328104615186693655
sage: pairing.order() == lA^eA
False
sage: pairing.order() == p
True
```

So I have problems proving the example parameters as described in the paper (but the same applies to the parameters of SIDHp503 of the lib PQCrypto-SIDH). Am I computing the Weil pairing wrong? Moreover, why should $|e(P_A,Q_A)|=l_A^{e_A}$ hold theoretically?

Comment: Your pairing computation is fine, it's your use or `order()` that's wrong. Check the Sage doc again. ;)

Comment: To explain @fkraiem's comment: In this setting, `.order()` returns the *additive* order, here equal to characteristic, while you are interested in the *multiplicative* order given by `.multiplicative_order()`.

Comment: Thanks! You're right and with the multiplicative order I get the correct result. Moreover when I calculate the Weil pairing for two dependent points (like $P$ and $2P$) I get 1. This makes sense because for supersingular curves the following holds $\forall P,Q \in G: e(P,Q) = 1$. But as $Q$ and $P$ are from two different subgroups in $E[l_A^{e_a}]$, I get something $\neq 1$.

Comment: Actually, this holds only if $G$ is cyclic, though try as I may I am unable to find any supersingular curve with a non-cyclic group...